# Comparing first element of the consecutive lists of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, compare, append

I have a list of tuples, each containing two elements. The first element of few sublists is common. I want to compare the first element of these sublists and append the second element in one lists. Here is my list:

```
myList=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,9),(3,10)]
```

I would like to make a list of lists out of it which looks something like this:`

```
NewList=[(2,3,4,5),(6,7,8),(9,10)]
```

I hope if there is any efficient way.

Comment: What if the first element of a sub-*tuple* is not common? You want a tuple of single element?

Comment: That's not a list of lists, but a lists of tuples; that doesn't make a difference to your question, but still, you should be aware of the difference

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to group the elements by the first subelement of each tuple:

```
myList=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,9),(3,10)]

from collections import OrderedDict

od  = OrderedDict()

for a,b in myList:
    od.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)

print(list(od.values()))
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

If you really want tuples:

```
print(list(map(tuple,od.values())))
[(2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

If you did not care about the order the elements appeared and just wanted the most efficient way to group you could use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

od  = defaultdict(list)

for a,b in myList:
    od[a].append(b)

print(list(od.values()))
```

Lastly, if your data is in order as per your input example i.e sorted you could simply use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by the first subelement from each tuple and extract the second element from the grouped tuples:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
print([tuple(t[1] for t in v) for k,v in groupby(myList,key=itemgetter(0))])
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Again the groupby will only work if your data is *sorted* by at least the first element.

Some timings on a reasonable sized list:

```
In [33]: myList = [(randint(1,10000),randint(1,10000)) for _ in range(100000)]

In [34]: myList.sort()

In [35]: timeit ([tuple(t[1] for t in v) for k,v in groupby(myList,key=itemgetter(0))])
10 loops, best of 3: 44.5 ms per loop

In [36]: %%timeit                                                               od = defaultdict(list)
for a,b in myList:
    od[a].append(b)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 33.8 ms per loop

In [37]: %%timeit
dictionary = OrderedDict()
for x, y in myList:
     if x not in dictionary:
        dictionary[x] = [] # new empty list
    dictionary[x].append(y)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 63.3 ms per loop

In [38]: %%timeit   
od = OrderedDict()
for a,b in myList:
    od.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 80.3 ms per loop
```

If order matters and the data is *sorted*, go with the *groupby*, it will get even closer to the defaultdict approach if it is necessary to map all the elements to tuple in the defaultdict.

If the data is not sorted or you don't care about any order, you won't find a faster way to group than using the *defaultdict* approach.

Comment: Thanks Padraic, for the code. This helped me to fix my naive problem.

Comment: agreed, this is probably the most efficient approach

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I retract my opinion that this is probably the most efficient way; see [my second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32667469/4433386).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, none of your approaches keep the order, if order is irrelevant my defaultdict approach will be more efficient than any of your two answers. Not sure on the groupby as I did not time it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham good point, but using `OrderedDict()` instead of `{}` would fix that, so I reffered to your answer in my updates. Assuming, of course, that "ordered" doesn't mean "in order of first occurence of first tuple member", but "sorted numerically".

Answer (score 4):

This feels like a task for a dictionary (if you don't know dictionaries yet, look them up on python.org). This is a very verbose example, so it's not what I'd write in everyday coding, but it's better to be verbose than unclear:

```
dictionary = collections.OrderedDict()
for x, y in myList:
    if not dictionary.has_key(x):
        dictionary[x] = [] # new empty list
    # append y to that list
    dictionary[x].append(y)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus for the suggestion. I would like to know about different modules of Python, which will make me fluent with Python. Let me know if you have any such better suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Having thought about this, the *most efficient approach* is probably this one-liner (assuming `dictionary` is an empty `dict`, i.e. `dictionary = {}` or `dictionary = OrderedDict()` like in [Padraic' excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667335/4433386)):

```
for x,y in myList: dictionary.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)
```

I'm not saying this is the easiest to read approach, but I like it :)

**EDIT** Ha! Benchmarking proved me wrong; the `setdefault` approach is slower than the `if not dictionary.has_key(x): dictionary[x]=[]` approach:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for x,y in myList:\n    if not dictionary.has_key(x):\n        dictionary[x]=[]\n    dictionary[x].append(y)", "from collections import OrderedDict\nmyList=[(1,2),(1,3),(
1,4),(1,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,9),(3,10)]\ndictionary=OrderedDict()")
2.2573769092559814
>>> timeit.timeit("for x,y in myList: dictionary.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)", "from collections import OrderedDict\nmyList=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,9),(3,10)]\ndictiona
ry=OrderedDict()")
3.3534231185913086
```

Of course, Padraic was still right: his `defaultdict` approach uses but 0.82s on my machine, so it's faster by a factor of 3.

Also, as Padraic pointed out: `dict.has_key(x)` has been deprecated, and one should use `x in dict` instead; however, I couldn't measure a speed difference.

Comment: `Having thought about this` did you also *measure*? BTW: why do you "copy" an answer?

Comment: @Wolf: I'm referring to, not copying :)

Comment: Yes, but for saying this that is *probably* the *most efficient approach* a comment will be enough.

Comment: It's a self-sufficient answer on it's own. I don't agree with your criticism on that. Also,  benchmarks!

Comment: `has_key` has been removed in python3, `if key  in dict` would make more sense

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: true, but Q says [tag:python-2.7].

Comment: After benchmarking? What's the value/point of your answer now?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: congrats, 3 times faster than my faster approach!

Comment: It is deprecated in python2, `in` is also faster than has_key

Comment: @Wolf: after benchmarking, my answer is still valuable because it shows a) another short, precise, pythonic approach, b) it compares that approach to other approaches, and c) it comes to the conclusion which approach is faster. Stop bickering; downvote please, and accept that I find my answer useful, because otherwise I wouldn't be giving it :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: even with laaaarge sample sizes, `timeit` can't spot a consistent difference between `in` and `has_key`. Updated answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I only tried to understand, so I asked. [Your first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32667397/2932052) was (and still is) my favorit to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import itertools

myList = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,9),(3,10)]
print [tuple(x[1] for x in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(myList, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Which displays:

```
[(2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: Sorry, total coincidence.

Comment: might want to mention the data must be in sorted order, at least as far as the first elements go