# Subset a list of tuples by max value in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

My question arise from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667320/comparing-first-element-of-the-consecutive-lists-of-tuples-in-python). I apologize, but I was not able to add a comment to ask my question under another answer because of my level. I have this list of tuples:

```
my_list = [('Scaffold100019', 98310), ('Scaffold100019', 14807), ('Scaffold100425', 197577), ('Scaffold100636', 326), ('Scaffold10064', 85415), ('Scaffold10064', 94518)]
```

I would like to make a dictionary which stores only the max value for each key defined as the first element of the tuple:

```
my_dict = {'Scaffold100019': 98310, 'Scaffold100425': 197577, 'Scaffold100636': 326, 'Scaffold10064': 94518}
```

Starting from the Marcus Müller's answer I have:

```
d = {}

#build a dictionary of lists
for x,y in my_list: d.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)

my_dict = {}

#build a dictionary with the max value only
for item in d: my_dict[item] = max(d[item])
```

In this way I reach my goal but, is there a sleeker way to complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that everything is greater than `None` and the dictionaries `get` method with `None` as the fallback return value.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for name, value in my_list:
...     if value > d.get(name, None):
...         d[name] = value
... 
>>> d
{'Scaffold100425': 197577, 'Scaffold10064': 94518, 'Scaffold100019': 98310, 'Scaffold100636': 326}
```

This will work for all values and hashes at most two times per loop.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this solution with only one loop, quite readable:

```
my_dict = {}

for x,y in my_list:
    if x in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict [x] = max (y, my_dict [x])
    else:
        my_dict [x] = y
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in my_list:
    d[key] = max(d[key], value)
```

The above code works on your example data, but will only work in general if each key has a maximum value that is nonnegative. This is because `defaultdict(int)` returns zero when no value is set, so if all values for a given key are negative, the resulting max will incorrectly be zero.

If purely negative values are possible for a given key, you can make the following alteration:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: -float('inf'))
```

With this alteration, negative infinity will be returned when a key isn't set, so negative values are no longer a concern.